# Python の venv が独立させる対象はライブラリのみですか？

Tags: python, python3, python-venv

最近venvを使い始めたのですが、一つ疑問があります。他のpython環境と独立しているといっても、あくまでpythonのライブラリが独立しているだけで、他のライブラリ(例えばCコンパイラ等)は共通、という理解で正しいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 3):

> pythonのライブラリが独立しているだけで、他のライブラリ(例えばCコンパイラ等)は共通

概ね、その認識で間違いありません。正確には、ライブラリに加えてPythonのバイナリも独立する場合があります。

`venv` で作られる仮想環境の挙動としては、Pythonや`pip`のバージョンを（シンボリックリンクやバイナリのコピーにより）指定し、それに対応するライブラリをその仮想環境の中にインストールしていくもののようです。

> venv モジュールは、軽量な "仮想環境" の作成のサポートを提供します。仮想環境には、仮想環境ごとの site ディレクトリがあり、これはシステムの site ディレクトリから分離させることができます。それぞれの仮想環境には、それ自身の Python バイナリ (様々な Python バージョンで環境を作成できます) があり、仮想環境ごとの site ディレクトリに独立した Python パッケージ群をインストールできます。
>
> [venv --- 仮想環境の作成 — Python 3.7.2 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/venv.html)